# Flex/ADL: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I'm attempting to run my AIR app under the ADL command line debugger including a [third party native extension](https://github.com/2bam/NativeJoystick) (I'm not using an IDE such as FlashDevelop). My app is intended for Windows desktop machines.

Compilation appears to work without issue:

```
$ amxmlc src/menustatemain.as
    -o src/menustatemain.swf
    -compiler.include-libraries C:\Users\Me\Downloads\AIRSDK_Compiler\frameworks\libs\player\21.0\playerglobal.swc
    -external-library-path+=extensions\ane\NativeJoystick.swc
    -use-network=false
    -verbose-stacktraces=true
    -debug=true
    -advanced-telemetry
    -omit-trace-statements=false
    -define=CONFIG::debug,false
    -define=CONFIG::test,true
Loading configuration: C:\Users\Me\Downloads\AIRSDK_Compiler\frameworks\air-config.xml

3383030 bytes written to C:\Users\Me\Documents\myproject\src\menustatemain.swf in 17.069 seconds
```

However when I try to run the app under ADL, it fails with this error:

```
$ adl
    -extdir extensions\ane_unzipped
    -profile extendedDesktop
    menustatemain.xml
VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code.
```

I've googled around and nothing I've tried has solved the issue. There are several similar questions on StackOverflow whose answers don't solve my issue. I have changed every setting I can find to dynamically link the extension at compile time and load it at runtime. I have a hunch this could be an issue with the extension itself, but I don't know how to verify that.

How can I debug this issue?

For context, this is the content of `menustatemain.xml`:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/21.0">
    <id>com.me.MyProject</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
    <filename>MyProject</filename>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>MyProject.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <width>640</width>
        <height>480</height>
        <maximizable>false</maximizable>
        <resizable>false</resizable>
    </initialWindow>
    <supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
    <extensions>
        <extensionID>com.iam2bam.ane.nativejoystick</extensionID>
    </extensions>
</application>
```

Also, I have the compiled and uncompiled versions of the native extension in a project subdirectory:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\myproject
    extensions\
        ane\
            NativeJoystick.ane
            NativeJoystick.swc
        ane_unzipped\
            NativeJoystick.ane\
                META-INF\
                    ...
```

Comment: Sounds like `adl` is picking up the wrong `Playerglobal.swc` or the wrong version of it.

Comment: I'm specifying it via `-compiler.include-libraries C:\Users\Me\Downloads\AIRSDK_Compiler\frameworks\libs\player\21.0\playerglobal.swc`. You think specifying a different version would help? How would I know which version to use?

Comment: I'm "assuming" that the player that your are compiling against is the correct one since 21.0 dir. I am talking about `adl`. Is that running from and against 21.0... i.e. does setting the `-runtime` option fix your #1079 error? Normally whenever I would see that error, `adl` is from the wrong version and/or it is not picking up the correct player swc and thus it fails as the player sac it is picking is a flash one and not an air based one... Also what happens when you package the app into a native air installer,  does it run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the wrong `playerglobal.swc`. The Flex SDK download comes with a "player" framework and an "AIR" framework, and I was incorrectly compiling against the "player" one, which doesn't allow native extensions. Changing my compile command did the trick:

```
-compiler.include-libraries C:\Users\Me\Downloads\AIRSDK_Compiler\frameworks\libs\air\21.0\airglobal.swc
```

Thanks for the tip @SushiHangover!